# Cisco switch VLANing based on MAC address

Tags: cisco, vlan, dynamic-vlan-assignment

Is it possible (or advisable) to tell a Cisco switch to VLAN based on MAC address? If so, how?

I know it can be done on a port-by-port basis, but I'd like more granularity than that.

We're using Catalyst 2960s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible - Yes, you use VLAN Membership Policy Server (VMPS) - [Clicky for general guidelines](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst4500/12-2/25ew/configuration/guide/conf/vmps.html)

Answer (score 1):

If the devices support it, you can also allow them to tag their own traffic with a vlan ID, the switch will honor it if the port is set to trunk mode.  That is useful in a scenario were you want VoIP phones on one vlan and computers on another (works even if the computer is connected to the phone's switch port).  It is not helpful if there are security reasons to separate the vlans.